# How to filter messages that do NOT have attachments using GMail query language?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

How do I filter out Gmail messages that DO NOT have attachments?

[Here is the documentation](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en) I'm trying to follow.

I can see that in order to include messages with attachments, I use the following query:

```
has:attachment
```

However, I do not see a way to do the inverse. I seek something like:

```
!has:attachment
```

What am I missing?

Comment: How about using `-has:attachment` by adding `-`? `-` is used as NOT. [Ref](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en)

Comment: @Tanaike That's what I think too, but there's no specific reference for that in the documentation _except_ "Remove messages from your results". Is that the relevant rule?

Comment: @Tedinoz I couldn't find the clearly document for this. I have used this operator from [this document](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en), because I thought that in Japanese language, I could understand like `specify keywords to exclude from search results`. By this, I thought that `-` can be used as NOT. But if this was not the replying you expect, I have to apologize.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Summary from comments

Both of the following work:

```
!has:attachment
```

and

```
-has:attachment
```

Comment: It didn't work when I need to search for emails belonging to a label with no attachments. To fix the issue I used **label:<label-name> (has: !attachment)**. And it worked.

Comment: @Ravi, that didn't work for me. I also needed to do a search within a group of labeled e-mails, with only one custom label and a default Inbox label. Maybe this "worked" for you for another reason that you didn't predict? I have seen this filter latch onto images in e-mail signatures, for example, with no file attachments at all. I am confident that this does not work. What did work for me was `label:my-label -has:attachment` as well as `label:my-label !has:attachment` as outlines in the accepted solution. You don't need to use parentheses in that expression by the way, it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any arguments for not having an attachment, but there is one for not having a user label. So you could have it filter select messages with attachments to an attachment label and have the select messages without a user label go somewhere else.

For Example:
[These two filters will delete messages forwarded from google voice if they don't have an attachment.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5aTl.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Besides what has already been suggested, there is a less obvious solution to this. Instead of trying to figure out the right symbol to use, you can simply use the Boolean word for *not*: **NOT**.

This will search for e-mails that **don't** have an attachment:

```
NOT has:attachment
```

As a bonus, you can use a double negative to express a positive (has attachment) using **NOT** – unlike the flipped version of that, which is what the original question was about (two positives don't make a negative). You may find this useful in some edge case scenarios perhaps. Note that you can't do this with the symbols `!` (exclamation mark) and `-` (hyphen/minus).

This will search for e-mails **that do have** an attachment:

```
NOT NOT has:attachment
```

Unlike this, which will not negate the negative and turn it into a positive:

```
--has:attachment
```

And neither will this:

```
!!has:attachment
```

**Warning:** I have seen this feature produce results that show a less than favorable list of e-mails with **no file attachments** at all, seemingly matching images in e-mail signatures (unconfirmed). It has something to do with how Google parses e-mails. Technically, a PNG file embedded in a signature – as a company logo – is an "attachment" alright, but this may not be very helpful in finding that PDF file attachment that you're looking for. So be aware of false positives – or false negatives – when using this feature in Gmail. It may be good enough for manually sifting through e-mails, but you can't rely on it for automation, like using filters to conditionally take action on incoming e-mails that either have or don't have a file attachment (which is what I wanted to do with it).